# django show user information in regroup only to user

Tags: django

Making a web app that lets a user log workouts. I have a page that groups all the logged workouts together by date, using regroup and a for  2 loops. How do I only show the user that is logged in information their own information. When I try to use a 3rd for loop (ex. {% for workout in workouts%}, {% if workout.person == user %})I just get 2 tables with the same information. Heres the code in my template.

```
    {% regroup workouts by date_of as dateof %}
      {%for date_of in dateof %}
        <table class="table table-striped table-dark mt-3">
          <thead>
            <th scope="col">{{date_of.grouper}}</th>
          </thead>
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Body Part</th>
              <th scope="col">Exercise</th>
              <th scope="col">Weight(lbs)</th>
              <th scope="col">Sets</th>
              <th scope="col">Reps</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
           <tbody>
             {% for workout in date_of.list %}
               <tr>
                 <td>{{workout.body_part}}</td>
                 <td>{{workout.exercise}}</td>
                 <td>{{workout.weight}}</td>
                 <td>{{workout.sets}}</td>
                 <td>{{workout.reps}}</td>
               </tr>
             {% endfor %}
           </tbody>
         </table>
       {% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can you show your **models.py**? If your workout model has ForeignKey of User, you might want to filter the query first and send only that user's workout data.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @gunsodo, after looking into it filtering the ListView with get_queryset solved the problem.